# SQL Value out of range

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with parameters like so:

```
@longitude decimal(5, 5),
@latitude decimal(5, 5),
@radius decimal(2, 2),
@DayOfWeek int
```

I pass in `-87.66826` for longitude and I get

> Parameter value '-87.66826' is out of range.

Am I missing something stupid here??

Answer (score 4):

Change `@longitude decimal(5,5)` to `@longitude decimal(7,5)`. Also change other decimal parameter types also.

`decimal(5,5)` means 0 digit before the decimal point and 5 digits after the decimal point.
But you need 2 digits before and 5 digits after the decimal point. So total length is 7.

Also these types is recommended for storing langitude and longitude in Sql Sevrer 2008.
You could read [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933876%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article for using these types.

> You should take a look at the new Spatial data-types that were
>   introduced in SQL Server 2008. They are specifically designed this
>   kind of task and make indexing and querying the data much easier and
>   more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

`Decimal(5,5)` means 5 total digits and 5 behind the decimal therefore it means zero digits before the decimal.

Also, depends on what SQL Server you use, there is also `geometry` data type that can store longitude and latitude

Answer (score 1):

Simple..

Change like this

```
@longitude decimal(7,5),
@latitude decimal(7,5),
@radius decimal(2,2),
@DayOfWeek int

decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
```

According to [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used,
>   valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms
>   for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent
>   to decimal.
>
> **p (precision)**
>
> The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both
>   to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must
>   be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default
>   precision is 18.
>
> **s (scale)**
>
> The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the
>   decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the
>   maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must
>   be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision
>   is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum
>   storage sizes vary, based on the precision.